# IsEnabled for a container?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to disable all controls inside a container - grid for example?
Thank you!

**UPD:** Although Silverlight’s Grid has IsEnabled property, there is definitely no IsEnabled property for Windows phone 7 Grid.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx -- could not find an `IsEnabled` on `Grid`

Comment: @DavidPerlman Yes, but it still shows on autocomplete when writing the XAML... very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several days of trying to disable all child controls inside Grid, I found following:

1. There is no IsEnabled property for WP7 Grid
2. We can still iterate through all children controls and set their IsEnabled property
3. We can also use the Visibility property for the Grid

Indeed, it doesn't make much sense showing controls if they are disabled, and it even saves some space and adds some interactivity when we hide and show it according to users' input.

I agree that this is not very convincing answer, but it is the only one that I have so far. :)

Comment: Domen Kogler's answer is a much better solution.

Answer (score 5):

For Silverlight, I have added a ScrollViewer around the Grid.  Since ScrollViewer inherits Control, I could set its IsEnabled property to false and that disabled all the controls inside the grid.

Comment: This works because ScrollViewer inherits from the ContentControl class that was mentioned in Domen Kogler's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the Grid or StackPanel with a ContentControl. ContentControls have an IsEnabled property.

Answer (score 0):

I have another option for you, using a StoryBoard. When your control is in certain state set the IsEnabled property of the container. This will disable the control. The state in the example below is the "ReorderEnabled" state. I used it to disable buttons on a listboxitem so the user can sort the items in the listbox.

```
                            <VisualState
                                x:Name="ReorderEnabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsEnabled)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="0.5"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
```

If you are not familiar with states. The best option to edit states is to use Expression Blend!