# Windows Phone popup open and parent page still enabled

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm having a problem when I open a popup control, this popup is smaller then my parent page and them all controls from the parent page are still working, how can I "disable" the parent page from getting focus when my popup is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parentpage.IsHitTestVisible = false

then the parentpage can not recive any event .

when the popup close , make sure had call IsHitTestVisible = true

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `IsEnabled` property of your parent to `false`, as described in the following question:

[IsEnabled for a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049605/isenabled-for-a-container)

Or, you could create an 'overlay', i.e. a full screen element such as a `Grid`, which has a higher z-index, that you make visible when your pop-up is open.