# How to create Semi transparent Grid using c# code

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, user-interface, silverlight-5.0

I am a `c#` `silverlight` developer and i am under a situation where i have created GUI using c# only(no use of xaml) . 
**How i created this GUI :**

I have coded for it in c# and there is 1 grid(with 3 number of rows) and inside that grid i have 3 more grids in each row of previous grid one corresponding to "`Automatic Skewing"` another grid in second row corresponds 
to "`Auto Model`" and the third one corresponds to "`Skew"`.

**What i have to do ?:**
Please note that the grid in third row contains a semi-transparent GUI. I want to do my gui semi transparent like this because i want to display the
GUI of the third row but i don't want to the user to click(edit) on third row , he must be able to see it with semi transparency (but can not click on it as you can see the third row (corresponding to `skew`) in snapshot below it is semi transparent and user cannot click on it).

**How to achieve this using c# code only(not xaml). Any Idea ?**

As you can see the Skew grid (3rd row) is semi transparent.

Comment: Like putting the content in a container, disabling it and maybe set an opacity lower than 1?

Comment: Yes thats what i wanted to know you are right.

Comment: @qqbenq but if i put opacity 0.5. I can stil edit the data. I don't wanty to edit the data /i mean i dont want any button clicks in that area. what to do  for it ?

Comment: @qqbenq and how to disable if i xanted to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your specification I think it would be the best to put all content of the third row into some [container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), set the `IsEnabled` property of it to `false`(as SilverLight's Grid seems to lack this property, you can try to wrap it in a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx)), and also set an `Opacity` lower than 1 to it.

Both the IsEnabled and the Opacity property affects the child elements.

Maybe it would be better to actually [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28VS.95%29.aspx) those values, as I suspect that the enabled/disabled state of the third row depends on some condition. (Both values - IsEnabled and Opacity - can be bound to the same condition, in case of the opacity you might want to use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

By the way: I feel it would be much easier with XAML...

Comment: but if i put opacity 0.5. I can stil edit the data. I don't wanty to edit the data /i mean i dont want any button clicks in that area. what to do for it ?

Comment: The IsEnabled property should take care of that, as it disables all child elements also.

Comment: IsEnabled  is not found in silverlight i guess. I tried to do this :  childGrid.IsEnabled = false; it gives red underline below  IsEnabled  (missing assmby reference n silverlight)

Comment: Grid doesn't have that in silverlight, you are right. Wrap it in ContentControl, for example. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049605/isenabled-for-a-container) for more help.

Comment: ContentControl means..Please note that i am coding in c# code only. How to wrap it Grid grig = new Grid() (suppose this "grid" contains GUI in third row) How i will achieve wrapping then ?

Comment: You create a ContentControl, set it's Content to your desired content (the third Grid), and add that ContentControl to your Grid's third Row. But I updated my answer with some links to MSDN, which can help you get started I hope.

Comment: Ok let me implement it . Will colme soon to mark as answer as it works